# How can I better handle config files?

Tags: config, raku

In a package I'm writing, I have a config module that looks like this:

```
use v6.d;
use JSON::Fast;
use PSBot::Tools;

sub EXPORT(--> Hash) {
    my Str $path = do if %*ENV<TESTING> {
        $*REPO.Str.IO.child('META6.json').e
            ?? $*REPO.Str.IO.child('t/config.json').Str         # For when testing using zef
            !! $*REPO.Str.IO.parent.child('t/config.json').Str; # For when testing using prove
    } elsif $*DISTRO.is-win {
        "%*ENV<LOCALAPPDATA>\\PSBot\\config.json"
    } else {
        "$*HOME/.config/PSBot/config.json"
    };

    unless $path.IO.e {
        note "PSBot config at $path does not exist!";
        note "Copy psbot.json.example there and read the README for instructions on how to set up the config file.";
        exit 1;
    }

    with from-json slurp $path -> %config {
        %(
            USERNAME               => %config<username>,
            PASSWORD               => %config<password>,
            AVATAR                 => %config<avatar>,
            HOST                   => %config<host>,
            PORT                   => %config<port>,
            SERVERID               => %config<serverid>,
            COMMAND                => %config<command>,
            ROOMS                  => set(%config<rooms>.map: &to-roomid),
            ADMINS                 => set(%config<admins>.map: &to-id),
            MAX_RECONNECT_ATTEMPTS => %config<max_reconnect_attempts>,
            GIT                    => %config<git>,
            DICTIONARY_API_ID      => %config<dictionary_api_id>,
            DICTIONARY_API_KEY     => %config<dictionary_api_key>,
            YOUTUBE_API_KEY        => %config<youtube_api_key>,
            TRANSLATE_API_KEY      => %config<translate_api_key>
        )
    }
}
```

Every time I make changes to the config file, I have to delete the precomp files for the changes to appear. Is there a way I can write this so the exports aren't defined at compile time so users don't have to do this?

Comment: My initial thought would be that you'd export subs that close over the %config that is initialized by an INIT phaser?

Comment: Anytime you find yourself wanting to use the file path of a repo to do something it’s probably wrong.

Comment: have you considered the `no precompilation` phaser? that will make it recompile every time the program starts, and other modules that use this one will probably also not be precompiled, but this script should run fast enough, i'd think

Comment: I wasn't aware that phaser existed!

Comment: .oO ( [Pragmatically](https://docs.perl6.org/language/pragmas) speaking, me mentioning timotimo's little mistake related to `precompilation` could well [phase](https://docs.perl6.org/language/phasers) those who don't understand why I'm commenting about it, and make those who do groan about my terrible humor, so I guess I'd better keep it to myself )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming I understand your intentions correctly, one way to do it would be this:

1. get rid of the `EXPORT` sub
2. place the computation of `$path` and `%config` into the module's mainline
3. declare your 'constants' as terms such as

   ```
   sub term:<USERNAME> is export { %config<username> }
   ```

Comment: This will work only if you only use this module once in a compilation unit.  If you'd like to be more flexible, you could implement something based on this code: `sub EXPORT($path = "something") { { PATH => $path } }` and then load the module with a positional parameter `use Foo <bar>" (which would set `PATH` to "bar" in that scope), or load the module (in another scope) with `use Foo`, in which case `PATH` will be "something" in that scope.

Answer (score 0):

After reading you guys' comments and the answer by @Christoph, I settled on this. This does what I want to do:

```
use v6.d;
use JSON::Fast;
use PSBot::Tools;
unit module PSBot::Config;

my Str $path = do if %*ENV<TESTING> {
    %?RESOURCES<test/config.json>.Str
} elsif $*DISTRO.is-win {
    Qh[%*ENV<LOCALAPPDATA>\PSBot\config.json]
} else {
    "$*HOME/.config/PSBot/config.json"
};

unless $path.IO.e {
    note "PSBot config at $path does not exist!";
    note "Copy config.json.example there and read the README for instructions on how to set up the config file.";
    exit 1;
}

my %config = from-json slurp $path;

sub term:<USERNAME>               is export  { %config<username>                   }
sub term:<PASSWORD>               is export  { %config<password>                   }
sub term:<AVATAR>                 is export  { %config<avatar>                     }
sub term:<HOST>                   is export  { %config<host>                       }
sub term:<PORT>                   is export  { %config<port>                       }
sub term:<SERVERID>               is export  { %config<serverid>                   }
sub term:<COMMAND>                is export  { %config<command>                    }
sub term:<ROOMS>                  is export  { set(%config<rooms>.map: &to-roomid) }
sub term:<ADMINS>                 is export  { set(%config<admins>.map: &to-id)    }
sub term:<MAX_RECONNECT_ATTEMPTS> is export  { %config<max_reconnect_attempts>     }
sub term:<GIT>                    is export  { %config<git>                        }
sub term:<DICTIONARY_API_ID>      is export  { %config<dictionary_api_id>          }
sub term:<DICTIONARY_API_KEY>     is export  { %config<dictionary_api_key>         }
sub term:<YOUTUBE_API_KEY>        is export  { %config<youtube_api_key>            }
sub term:<TRANSLATE_API_KEY>      is export  { %config<translate_api_key>          }
```